# How to change Windows 10 incorrect password error message?

Tags: windows-10, passwords

When I enter the wrong password at the login screen, I get the following message:

> The password is incorrect. Try again.

How can I change this to my desired error message?

Comment: So, you want a different message when you enter the wrong password? What version of Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, I use 1903.

Comment: Check out the answers here: https://superuser.com/questions/803093/what-are-the-default-english-error-messages-for-windows-password-policies

Comment: @music2myear there are 1759 files. which one?

Comment: 1759 of what file? There's only going to be one winlogon localization file that applies to your question.

Comment: winlogon does not have this message.

Comment: Did you follow the directions in the linked thread? What did you or did you not find?